# Phonegap build with android geolocation

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-build

I'm writting an android and iphone app using phonegap 3.0.

So far I have been only compiling the apps remotely using phonegap build.

Now I'm trying to add the [geolocation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation) plugin to my app, and in iphone was easy, since I only had to modify the config.xml file.

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
</feature>
```

So far so good, the problem was that when adding geolocation to android, the documentation indicates that I have set the following configuration:

```
(in app/res/xml/config.xml)
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker" />
</feature>


(in app/AndroidManifest.xml)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
```

But I don't have an AndroidManifest.xml file. I could generate the complete android app using:

```
cordoba platform add android
```

But I'm not sure if this is what I should do. 
Is is what I should be doing? or there is a way to add geolocation without generating the entire android project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit confused because you say you are using phonegap 3.0 and you also mention phonegap-build (highest is 2.9). If you are in fact using phonegap-build, the only thing you need is in your config.xml:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

Comment: I'm reading the documentation for phonegap 3.0, in which commands like phonegap run android, build the app using phonegap build. It seems that everything is working right now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My geolocation worked on IOS but not on Android. So I Added to config.xml

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
```

As explained by Dom.This was not sufficient. I wanted to share what I did step by step because I lost about 18h of dev time looking for the solution.

This however did not reslove the problem. So I added the plugin using my IDE. [image]

This added the following to the config:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" version="2.2.0" />
```

I then went inside the plugin.xml under the plugin directorty. 
[image]

[image]

And looked if the following was added.

```
 <!-- android -->
    <platform name="android">

        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        </config-file>

...
```

It was, so I rebooted the device. (on the Ionic forum they say, it might help) 
When reinstalling the app I checked for the permission. And it was added. So for the bad Q of the last pic but I took a pic with my cam for it. Hope this helps

[image]